# WEBMethods (Java) not writing to network drive?

Tags: c#, java, webmethods

I cannot get WEBMethods to write to my companies network drive. I can however access the network drive with a simple call in C# but cannot in Java. The network drive and the local drive Q: drive are shared to the same location. So I should be able to access the drive through the drive name and server or through the Q: drive.

I changed the drive name around so that no information could be seen that might tell someone drive names.

Question: Why can I access my Q: drive through C# (write and read) but not Java?

Code: (Java)

```
      writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("\\\\A\\B\\S\\A B\\P\\T\TWM\\" + matcher.group(1) + ".txt")));
```

C# Code:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Read the file as one string. 
            string text1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Q:\\S\ABCPS\T\TWM\T.txt");
            //string text1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"\\E5\D\SYS\Tes\T.txt");
            //string text1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"\\DS\ES\S\ABKS\T\TM\T.txt");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteText.txt = {0}", text1);

        string myLine = "Test line of code!!!!";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Q:SY\ACS\T\U\N.txt", myLine);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't related to the [webMethods] tag, so you're probably missing your target audience for this one.

However, you are missing one '\' in your Java program's path - "..T\TWM.." - so that may be where your issue lies.

BTW in general (excluding UNC paths) you can use forward slashes (/) in Java paths, and Java will automatically translate then when required for e.g. Windows.  This does make pathnames in code easier to read, and portable to other operating systems (FWIW).